# Очень большой Double to BigDecimal

Tags: java, математика, bigdecimal

Всем привет.
При создании (конвертации) обьекта BigDecimal c 32-мя знаками у меня получается значение типа 1.0E-30

```
    BigDecimal delta = new BigDecimal("0.000000000000000000000000000001", mc);
или так:
    BigDecimal delta = new BigDecimal(0.000000000000000000000000000001d, mc);
    BigDecimal delta = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.000000000000000000000000000001d);
```

В общем результат один
**Output:
DELTA: 1.0E-30**

Как мне получить нормальный результат с 30 знаками (но это не предел) ?
использую JavaHome=jdk1.8_131 хотя при 1.8_51 тоже самое
Заранее благодарен за ответ!

Comment: Можно так: `BigDecimal.valueOf(0.000000000000000000000000000001d).toPlainString()`

Comment: Да спасибо большое - это работает.
Но  для моего случая здесь еще нужно дописать вот так 
`BigDecimal.valueOf(0.000000000000000000000000000001d).toPlai‌​nString().substring(0, 32)`
в этом случае оно действительно будет брать 30 знаков после запятой + я еще решил эту проблему с помощью
`String.format("%.30f", d)`

Comment: @Alex чтож, тогда стоит ответить на свой вопрос, что бы другие (если вдруг случайно найдут ваш вопрос) увидели ответ)